# implementing substraction on listview

Tags: java, android

Hi I am new on this page.

I am developing an app, on android, I have a listview that populate a list of numbers, in one column I have the value of items. I can add them and sum them in a variable total, I use a onItemClick event on the listview, in order of delete the rows, I want to delete the row value from the total variable for example.

If i have the values 8 90 3, the total is 101, but if I delete the value 90 that is the row id 1, how i can delete it from total and set the new total to 11 that is new total left from the substraction.

I could Implement a solution but it only substract on value if i put two values it gave me a error here my implementation:

```
 mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
         public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {


             int k = (int) id;

             List<Data> dcontrol;
             dcontrol = data; 

             for(Data dt: dcontrol){
                residuo = Integer.parseInt(dt.getY());
               }

             resultNumber = resultNumber - residuo; 
             System.out.println(resultNumber);

             updateTextField();


             sh.deleteCloudPrint(data.remove(k));

             mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

             }

         });
```

Comment: If am not wrong you're displaying the numbers on TextView, right ??

Comment: yes I use a function: updateTextfield(inTotal.setText(symbol+String.valueOf(resultNumber))

Comment: Please provide your full code so that i can help you as fast as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your adapter looks like:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> a2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, al);
```

Then you can try this:

```
listView.setAdapter(a2);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
                                            {
                                                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) 
                                                {
                                                    String s1;
                                                    s1 = (String) ((TextView)arg1).getText();

                                                    int value = Integer.parseInt(s1);

                                                    total = total - value;
                                                } 
                                            }
                                        );
```

Hope this code works for you.

Comment: I could Implement a solution but it only substract on value if i put two values it gave me a error here my implementation:int k = (int) id;
              
                 List<Data> dcontrol;
                 dcontrol = data; 

                 for(Data dt: dcontrol){
                 residuo = Integer.parseInt(dt.getY());
                   }
                 
                 resultNumber = resultNumber - residuo; 
                 System.out.println(resultNumber);

                 updateTextField();